# error when using table rowtype as the function's return type

Tags: postgresql

I have following simple postgresql function definition,

I have defined a table named `t_0003`, it has 3 columns, named `a,b,c`

When I use this function , it complains that  there are errors around `t_0003%ROWTYPE` in the statement `RETURNS t_0003%ROWTYPE AS $$`.

If I change `RETURNS t_0003%ROWTYPE AS $$`  to `RETURNS RECORD AS $$`,then it works fine.

I would ask why there are error for  `RETURNS t_0003%ROWTYPE AS $$`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_0003()
RETURNS t_0003%ROWTYPE AS $$ --error 
DECLARE
 v_c t_0003%ROWTYPE;  
BEGIN
   select a,b,c into v_c from t_0003;
    return v_c;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select func_0003()
```

Comment: Just remove the `%ROWTYPE` Oraclism.

Comment: Oraclism nice word @Laurenz Albe :).

Comment: There are other problems with the function: the query explicitly enumerates the columns to be returned into `v_c`, which will cause incorrect results if the table's column order changes; and the query will populate `v_c` with an indeterminate row if the table has more than one row. The first problem can be addressed by either replacing `a, b, c` with `*` in the query so that column order is tied to the table's definition, or by replacing `INTO v_c` with `INTO v_c.a, v_c.b, v_c.c`. The second problem can be addressed by adding `ORDER BY` to the query.